# trying to create a bmesh from csv coordinate list

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, csv

Hello fellow Blender snakehandlers,

I have a list of coordinates in a csv file and I would like to create a mesh with only vertices from it.

When I run it, it throws the following error, which I can't decipher.
Any ideas on how to make this work? Thank you!

```
line 54, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 429, in from_pydata
    self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence
```

CSV

```
id,x,y,z,r,g,b
0,0.30778491,0.12740749,0.04903458,174.0,84.0,118.0
```

PYTHON

```
import bpy
import csv, os, bmesh, math

#filepaths
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

blendname = bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
blendname = os.path.splitext(blendname)[0]
if blendname:
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = blendname
print(blendname)

some_dict = {}

# DO POINTS    
csvpoints= directory+"/csv/3d-points.csv" 
pointsReader = csv.reader(open(csvpoints, newline=''), delimiter=',')

#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

obj = bpy.context.object

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []

for idx, row in enumerate(pointsReader):
    #print(idx, row)
    id = row[0]
    print("id = "+ id)
    x = row[1]
    print("x = " + x)
    y = row[2]
    print("y = " + y)
    z = row[3]
    print("z = " + z)
    vert = (x,y,z) 
    verts.append(vert)

#create mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("wave")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("wave",mesh)

#create mesh from python data
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],[])
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

#set mesh location
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
```

Comment: Might be related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36837/convert-csv-latitude-longtitude-to-blender-coordinates?s=1|49.5043

Answer (score 1):

The manuals suggest using the csvreader in a *with* block.

You made two mistakes.

1. You have to skip the first csv line, since it doesn't hold any values. (Or treat it differently.)
2. You have to parse the numeric values. `float(row[0])`

---

Working example.

```
import bpy
import csv, os, bmesh, math

#filepaths
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []

csvpoints= directory+"/points.csv"
pointsReader = csv.reader(open(csvpoints, newline=''), delimiter=',')   

with open(csvpoints, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    pointsReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idx, row in enumerate(pointsReader):
        if (idx > 0):
            vert = (float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2])) 
            verts.append(vert)

obj = bpy.context.object

#create mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("wave")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("wave",mesh)

#create mesh from python data
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],[])
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)


#set mesh location
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)
```

Comment: Ah that works! Which manual do you refer to? I googled and came up with nothing suitable. A lot of code examples parse csvs with a for loop...

Comment: @anf Just various [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#module-contents).

Comment: I have another csv that lists edges like so:

source,target
214,0

how do i create edges between the verts in the mesh? a nested for loop? with itertools?

`with open(csvedges, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile2:
    edgesReader = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idy, row in enumerate(pointsReader):
        if (idy > 0):
            edge = mesh.verts.[edgereader.row[0]], mesh.verts[edgereader.row[1]])
            edges.append(edge)
            #print(idy)
            mesh.edges.new((mesh.verts[0], bm.verts[1]))`

Comment: @anf Go ahead and ask a new question. =)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96070/how-to-create-edges-in-existing-mesh-based-on-csv-with-python
Vielen Dank / thank you for your help! :)