# How to create edges in existing mesh based on a list of vertex indices with Python

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, csv

I parse 2 csvs, one with vertex coordinates

```
id,x,y,z,r,g,b
0,0.30778491,0.12740749,0.04903458,174.0,84.0,118.0
1,0.3315943,0.0922608,0.08094925,174.0,84.0,118.0
```

and one listing edges like so

```
source,target
214,0
214,1
```

After creating the vertices in a mesh, how do i add the edges between the vertex indices listed in the second csv?

Do I need a nested for loop? itertools? thank you!

```
import bpy
import csv, os, bmesh, math

#filepaths
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []

csvpoints= directory+"/csv/3d-points.csv"

csvedges = directory+"/csv/3d-edges.csv"

pointsReader = csv.reader(open(csvpoints, newline=''), delimiter=',')   

edgesReader = csv.reader(open(csvedges, newline=''), delimiter=',')

with open(csvpoints, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    pointsReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idx, row in enumerate(pointsReader):
        if (idx > 0):
            vert = (float(row[1]), float(row[2]), float(row[3])) 
            verts.append(vert)


obj = bpy.context.object

#create mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("edgewave")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("edgewave",mesh)

#create mesh from python data
mesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,[])
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

#set mesh location
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)

with open(csvedges, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile2:
    edgesReader = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idy, row in enumerate(pointsReader):
        if (idy > 0):
            edge = mesh.verts.[edgesReader.row[0]], mesh.verts[edgesReader.row[1]])
            edges.append(edge)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I simplified it a bit. I later found out I had a syntax error in my loop - I was doing the right thing in principle before.
The object you are adding edges to has to be selected and in edit mode when running the script.

```
import bpy
import csv, os, bmesh, math

#filepaths
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []



csvedges = directory+"/csv/3d-edges.csv"



edgesReader = csv.reader(open(csvedges, newline=''), delimiter=',')


current_obj = bpy.data.objects["wave"]  # particular object by name


obj = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)


if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

with open(csvedges, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile2:
    edgesReader = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idy, row in enumerate(edgesReader):
        if (idy > 0) :
            #print(idy)
            bm.edges.new((bm.verts[int(row[0])], bm.verts[int(row[1])]))
```