# Using nodes to visualize parallel straight lines and control their thickness

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to visualize many straight lines (around 100 up to 200) of differnet lenght parallel to each other in a 2D viewing.

The Input should be a .txt-data with 2 numbers per line, which determinates my starting- and endpoint. Like this:

```
 0,200
 10,200
 50,150
 0,50,120,200
 0,150
 ...
```

The next step would be to change the thickness of the lines.

Maybe you're able to explain me a solution or tell me were to start, but I'm just a beginner so I may not understand every explanation.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please document your "first try-outs" with Blender nodes, so others can see what you attempted. [Maybe related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96065/30849). Since nodes are usually used for compositing 2D images or renders I don't see how they could be helpful with your problem. Do you possibly mean [animation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes).

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Also please edit the title of the question to describe the problem clearly.

Comment: This isn't really a nodes question, it's a scripting question.  To get your input into Blender, you're either going to enter it by hand or script its input.  Once you begin scripting, this is a problem where the nodes part of the solution is trivial.  A lot of the implementation can be traded between Python and nodes, but Python is the easier way to do it.